# Updating web.xml using shell script to change the param-value

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have below entry in web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.ENABLED</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am doing some repackaging work using shell script and want to change the value from 'false' to 'true' only for the given param-name. How can I do it using sed/awk command? Note that there are multiple param-name and param-value entries with 'false' values which shouldn't change alongwith.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v tgt='oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.ENABLED' '
    found { sub(/false/,"true"); found=0 }
    { found = index($0,"<param-name>" tgt "</param-name>" }
' file
```

Comment: getting syntax error - awk: found { sub(/false/,"true"); found=0 } { found = index($0,"<param-name>" tgt "</param-name>" }                                                                                      ^ syntax error

Comment: OK, so fix the syntax error. I'm sure if you put a minutes thought into it you'd see what the problem is. It's just another programming language, it's not magic.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't parse XML with regex !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) & [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) (a proper XML parser):

```
 xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/context-param/param-value" -v 'true' file.xml
```

To match the Nth element, you can adapt it a bit (starting from 1) :

```
 xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/context-param[10]/param-value[5]" -v 'true' file.xml
```

Comment: Looks like I need to install xmlstartlet for this which is not possible for me. Further it uses the count which may change in future and thats a risk..

Comment: If `xmlstarlet` is not installed, maybe `perl` is ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "/<context-param>/,/<\/context-param>/ {
   /<context-param>/ h
   /<context-param>/ !H
   /<\/context-param>/ {
     x;s/<param-name>oracle.adf.view.rich.automation.ENABLED<\/param-name>/&/
     t chg
     b
:chg
     s/<param-value>false</<param-value>true</
     }" web.xml
```

treat section  context-param, load in buffer, check if param-name is the good one and change false to true if iti is the case